# Query hashmap structure with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hashmap, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have two questions regarding mapping and querying a java hashmap in elasticsearch.

Does this mapping make sense in elasticsearch (is it the correct way to map a hashmap)?:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "itemsMap": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "itemVal1": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "itemVal2": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is some example data:

```json
{
  "itemsMap": {
    "2021-12-31": {
      "itemVal1": 100.0,
      "itemVal2": 150.0,
    },
    "2021-11-30": {
      "itemVal1": 200.0,
      "itemVal2": 50.0,
    }
  }
}
```

My queries don't seem to work. For example:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "itemsMap",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "itemsMap.key": "2021-11-30"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I query such a structure? I have the possibility to change the mapping if it's necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR;

The way you are uploading your data, nothing is stored in `key`.
You will have fields named `2021-11-30` ... and `key` is going to be empty.

Either you have a limited amount of "dates" and this is a viable options (less than 1000) else your format is not viable on the long run.

If you don't want to change your doc, here is the query

```json
GET /71525899/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "itemsMap",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "itemsMap.2021-12-31"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## To understand

If you inspect the mapping by querying the index

```
GET /<index_name>/_mapping
```

You will see that the number of fields name after your date is going to grow.

And in all your doc, `itemsMap.key` is going to be empty. (this explain why my previous answer did not work.

## A more viable option

Keep your mapping, update the shape of your docs.

They will look like

```json
{
  "itemsMap": [
    { 
      "key": "2021-12-31", 
      "value": { "itemVal1": 100, "itemVal2": 150 }
    },
    { 
      "key": "2021-11-30",
      "value": { "itemVal1": 200, "itemVal2": 50 }
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
DELETE /71525899


PUT /71525899/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "itemsMap": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "itemVal1": {
                "type": "double"
              },
              "itemVal2": {
                "type": "double"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"71525899"}}
{"itemsMap":[{"key":"2021-12-31", "value": {"itemVal1":100,"itemVal2":150}},{"key":"2021-11-30", "value":{"itemVal1":200,"itemVal2":50}}]}
{"index":{"_index":"71525899"}}
{"itemsMap":[{"key":"2022-12-31", "value": {"itemVal1":100,"itemVal2":150}},{"key":"2021-11-30", "value":{"itemVal1":200,"itemVal2":50}}]}
{"index":{"_index":"71525899"}}
{"itemsMap":[{"key":"2021-11-31", "value": {"itemVal1":100,"itemVal2":150}},{"key":"2021-11-30", "value":{"itemVal1":200,"itemVal2":50}}]}



GET /71525899/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "itemsMap",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "itemsMap.key": "2021-12-31"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not working. It returns 0 hits.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I don't have much experience with elasticsearch but this:      GET /<index_name>/_mapping 
really made me understand the mapping better.

Comment: Glad it helped man !